# how to stop jQuery from running on one div when using it on a div within the first div?

Tags: jquery

how do i stop the first piece of code from running directly after the second one runs? I know it is because my 'work-title' class is inside my 'work-entry' div. How do I stop the .slideDown() function from happening after clicking the .work-title? The slideDown works fine, but the slideDown function will also run right after the slideUp function. How do I stop that from happening?

My code:

```
$(".work-entry").on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.work-entry').find('.work-panel').slideDown();


});

$('.work-title').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.work-entry').find('.work-panel').slideUp();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevent event bubble the DOM tree:

```
$('.work-title').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).closest('.work-entry').find('.work-panel').slideUp();
});
```